# Developing in the NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am trying to put together a very light built of netbeans 7.1 RC2.

What are the minimum requirement of clusters from the Netbeans Plaform to edit, compile and run a java program?

I am looking for only the java essential clusters and modules since all dependencies will be resolved by Netbeans

Also I am trying to cover all the bases with the java editor so i need support for SE, EE, FX and possibly others that might be required or desired.

Comment: 1. The title it's too broad and does not specify your objective  2. This is so specific about a certain software that I'm not sure it belongs here. Have you also asked in the Netbeans dev forum/list?

Comment: Yes I have, and I believe that it is a good question in the context of java and netbeans platform which are tags in this site.

Comment: @ArturGVieira It's too broad. NetBeans and a JDK are all you need to develop a Java app in NetBeans. Not sure what you mean by "clusters" in this context.

Comment: The Netbeans Platform is a Swing IDE running on top of a platform. clusters are what gives Netbeans its features. Clusters are composed of modules. Modules are an aggregation of classes that work together to provide some service...Something like that at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing.

If you want to build an application that "edits, compiles and runs a java program" then you need at least the "ide" cluster (and its dependencies). You'll end up with a NetBeans clone, basically.

If you want to "edit, compile and run" (within NetBeans) a "java program" that uses the NetBeans platform then you need the "platform" cluster only.

Comment: I really need as clone, because I am planning on packaging the Netbeans Platform program with another program so that netbeans is a service. If you want to know what I have in mind check out http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=45437

Comment: btw nice last name, sorry if the question is confusing or complicated = )

Comment: The platform cluster only comes with the 5 main modules which operate the back end, i need a better understanding of which clusters package the Java part of the Netbeans Platform. I also need the complete ide for Java editing, compiling and running.

Comment: I see. You'll need most of the clusters if you want to have Java support. The NetBeans mailing lists will be of great help for your task